# Load a memo control from external file using Smart Mobile Studio 1.1

Tags: smart-mobile-studio

Ho do I load a memo control from external file

example:  \res\info.txt

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the folks at SMS have come up with a quick and dirty solution until they can add a LoadFromUrl method in th TStringList

http://smartmobilestudio.com/forums/topic/loading-memo-from-file-resinfo-txt/

Their solution works by adding `LoadFromURL` method to the TStringList class via a helper object. The code below is copied from the Smart Mobile Studio forum and adjusted to work with Smart Mobile Studio 1.1. You can use it unitil `TStringList.LoadFromUrl` appears in the RTL.

```
type
  TStringlistHelper = class helper for TStringList
    procedure LoadFromUrl(aUrl:String;Callback: TProcedureRef = nil);
  end;

procedure TStringlistHelper.LoadFromUrl(aUrl:String;
            Callback:TProcedureRef);
var
  mRequest: TW3HttpRequest;
begin
  mRequest:=TW3HttpRequest.Create;
  mRequest.OnDataReady:=procedure (Sender:TW3HttpRequest)
  begin
    self.text:=Sender.ResponseText;
    if assigned(Callback) then Callback;
    w3_callback(sender.free,100);
  end;
  mRequest.Get(aUrl);
end;
```

Just add this code to some unit and then use this unit in your project.